# PORO presenter breaks url helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mvp

I have started creating my rails presenters using a PORO approach. Example presenter resides in `app/presenters/band_presenter.rb` and here is it's code:

```
class BandPresenter
  def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
    @band.send(m)
  end

  def initialize(band)
    @band = band
  end

  def thumb_url(size = :large_s)
    @band.images[size.to_s] if @band.images
  end
end
```

And it works good. However, if i'll use an instance of that presenter in rails url helper methods, it breaks them. For example:

```
@band = Band.find(1)
= link_to @band.name, band
# => /bands/1

@band = @band.find(1)
@band = BandPresenter.new(@band)
= link_to @band.name, band
# => /%23%3CBandPresenter:0x007f9139c50db0%3E/1
```

Which seems completely legit. My question is - can i somehow make my presenter support such way of using url helpers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining a to_param method

```
class BandPresenter
  def to_param
    @band.id
  end

  def model_name
    @band.model_name
  end
end
```

Another option that might help is defining `respond_to_missing?`, see here: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/always-define-respond-to-missing-when-overriding

```
class BandPresenter
  def respond_to_missing?(method_name, include_private = false)
    @band.respond_to?(method_name, include_private) || super
  end
end
```

Comment: Defining `respond_to_missing` is not enough, OP should also define `method_missing` to 'delegate' missing calls to `@band`. Also, your first attept of solution wouldn't work either, because you should define not only `to_param` but also `model_name` method.

Comment: I see no reason for me to copy-paste code from the OP, of course I meant he should add the methods additionally to his already existing ones (he already has `method_missing` defined). Thanks for comment about `model_name`, that's why I said "try", since I did not test if it was enough.

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice OP already defined `method_missing`. BTW `model_name` should be delegated to `Band` class, not instance, and `BandPresenter` class should respond to it, like in following example: https://gist.github.com/myobie/981251.

Comment: I added `model_name` for completeness sake.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it work if you define `respond_to_missing?` without defining `to_param`?